cannot run DLT-fraud-detection-sql Demo Notebook
I want to run the Databricks DLT fraud detection demo. The first cell of the notebook is designed to load the data with the following command:
%run ../_resources/01-load-data
However, I encountered an issue with this step and it failed to run. I would like to know where I can obtain the data required for this demo. It is supposed to be their live data. What can I do to resolve this issue if I am using the Databricks Community Edition?
I imported the notebook from the Databricks website and attempted to run it in the Community Edition.
Please help!
